# SwiftUI: Closing opened window on macOS causes crash

Tags: macos, swiftui, window

I can open a new window, but if I close it using the window's close button then my app crashes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        Button(action: {openMyWindow()},
               label: {Image(systemName: "paperplane")})
            .padding()
    }
}

func openMyWindow()
{
    var windowRef:NSWindow
    windowRef = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 600),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    windowRef.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: WindowView())
    windowRef.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}

struct WindowView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        Text("Hello World")
            .padding()
    }
}

@main

struct Open_WindowApp: App 
{
    var body: some Scene 
    {
        WindowGroup 
        {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I think I need to keep my windowRef active, but how do I do this?

Comment: please include the stack of the crashing thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to keep reference to window, try the following

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    @State private var windowRef: NSWindow?

    var body: some View
    {
        Button(action: {openMyWindow()},
               label: {Image(systemName: "paperplane")})
            .padding()
    }

    func openMyWindow()
    {
        // handle previously opened window here somehow if needed
        guard windowRef == nil else { return }

        windowRef = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 600),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        windowRef?.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: WindowView())
        windowRef?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: this doesn't compile, because the last two lines of `openMyWindow()` need to unwrap the optional. once we fix that, it runs, but only until the 2nd time you click the button, then it crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) at the guard statement

Answer (score 2):

1. declare windowRef outside the scope of `openMyWindow()`
2. if the window already exists, bring to front, don't make another.
3. keep the window from being dealloc'd on close, either

   - `windowRef.isReleasedWhenClosed = false` (shown below) ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419062-isreleasedwhenclosed)), OR
   - `someGlobalWindowController = NSWindowController(window: w)`

```
    var windowRef: NSWindow? 
    func openMyWindow()
    {
        if let curWindow = windowRef {
            curWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            return
        }
        let w = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 600),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        w.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: WindowView())
        w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        w.isReleasedWhenClosed = false // <--- important
        windowRef = w
    }
```